# kadira:flow-router route executes before the DOM is rendered

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use flow-router with react in meteor. The route is defined like so:

```
  FlowRouter.route('/',
     {
        action(){
           const containerElement = document.getElementById("react-root");
           if (containerElement) {
              const app = React.createElement("<App/>");
              ReactDOM.render(app, containerElement);
           } else {
              console.log("no element react-root found");
           }
        }
     })
```

and the HTML is very basic:

```
    <head>
        <title>Todo List</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="react-root">react-root</div>
    </body>
```

when I launch meteor and navigate to localhost:3000 I get `react-root` on the page and the message `no element react-root found` in the console.

I have tried to wrap the route definition inside `Meteor.startup(` but then I get an error that the route `/` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/issues/183#issuecomment-117371588) from arunoda:

> Now Flow Router does not wait for DOM. We do it in the layout layer.

So until you choose to use [React Layout](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-react-layout) or [Blaze Layout](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout), you can wrap your code like this to trigger it only when the DOM is loaded:

```js
FlowRouter.route('/',
 {
    action(){
     $(function () {
       const containerElement = document.getElementById("react-root");
       if (containerElement) {
          const app = React.createElement("<App/>");
          ReactDOM.render(app, containerElement);
       } else {
          console.log("no element react-root found");
       }
     });
    }
 })
```